# Phonegap Application Get Crashed on backbutton click for android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on a PhoneGap Application in combination with [Angular JS](https://angularjs.org/). Here first off all, some information for you:

1. Cordova version: **3.6.3**
2. Angular JS version: **v1.4.0-rc.0**

Now I have overridden the backbutton fuctionality for android with this code:

```
CommonService.checkConnection();
if (sessionStorage.Device == "Android Mobile" || sessionStorage.Device    ==       "Android Tablet") {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKey, false);
    }
```

My `onBackKey` function looks like this:

```
function onBackKey() {
   alert("onBackKey");
}
```

Now this function is called as i needed but the android application also get crashed (when i click back button in android).

Edit:--

I am getting following Error Log:-

```
    07-09 14:13:26.925: D/WebView(24377):         loadUrl=javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('backbutton');
    07-09 14:13:26.939: D/CordovaActivity(24377): onMessage(exit,null)
    07-09 14:13:27.076: D/CordovaActivity(24377): Paused the application!
    07-09 14:13:27.076: D/ActivityThread(24377): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{41f61d68 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41f61538 {com.Corecon.coreconapp/com.Corecon.coreconapp.CoreconMobile}}
    07-09 14:13:27.079: W/PluginManager(24377): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to App.exitApp blocked the main thread for 140ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
    07-09 14:13:27.089: D/ActivityThread(24377): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY_FINISHING handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@41f61538


    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.test.testapp has leaked window    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{425281b8 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-698,384} that was originally added here 07-08 12:45:43.883: E/WindowManager(14991)
```

I can't figure out why this happens. Can you help me solving this problem, do you have any ideas why pressing the back button forces my app to crash?

Comment: what is the error you see in your logs?

Comment: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.test.testapp has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{425281b8 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-698,384} that was originally added here
07-08 12:45:43.883: E/WindowManager(14991):